# IEnumerable to typed Dictionary

Tags: c#, iterator, hash-map, xamarin

### Scenario

A portable controls/widgets library for [Xamarin.Forms](http://www.xamarin.com/forms) (PCL Profile 111) contains a **combobox**/dropdown/picker control where the **`ItemsSource`** property is an **`IEnumerable`**.

- The ItemsSource can be populated with any IEnumerable of objects.
- The combobox displays value by

  - `DisplayMemberPath: string`
- The combobox syncs selection:

  - `SelectedItem : object`
  - `SelectedIndex: int`

To do all this the IEnumerable must be parsed so we can

- Select index
- Select item from source collection

### The tricky part

Parse `IEnumerable` to `Dictionary<object, object>` in a Portable Class Library.
The `sourceDictionary` field is used to sync the "selected" properties as described above.

```
    private Dictionary<object, object> sourceDictionary;

    /// <summary>
    ///     Parse type of ItemsSource as Dictionary and populate <see cref="Picker.Items" /> and
    ///     <see cref="sourceDictionary" />.
    /// </summary>
    private void PopulateItemsAndSelectionValuesFromDictionary()
    {
        // TODO: Better way to get Dictionary from IEnumerable
        if (this.ItemsSource is Dictionary<object, object>)
        {
            foreach (var newItem in (Dictionary<object, object>)this.ItemsSource)
            {
                this.AddToItemsAndSelectionValues(newItem.Key, newItem.Value);
            }
        }
        else if (this.ItemsSource is Dictionary<object, string>)
        {
            foreach (var newItem in (Dictionary<object, string>)this.ItemsSource)
            {
                this.AddToItemsAndSelectionValues(newItem.Key, newItem.Value);
            }
        }
        else if (this.ItemsSource is Dictionary<object, int>)
        {
            foreach (var newItem in (Dictionary<object, int>)this.ItemsSource)
            {
                this.AddToItemsAndSelectionValues(newItem.Key, newItem.Value);
            }
        }
        else if (this.ItemsSource is Dictionary<int, object>)
        {
            foreach (var newItem in (Dictionary<int, object>)this.ItemsSource)
            {
                this.AddToItemsAndSelectionValues(newItem.Key, newItem.Value);
            }
        }
        else if (this.ItemsSource is Dictionary<string, object>)
        {
            foreach (var newItem in (Dictionary<string, object>)this.ItemsSource)
            {
                this.AddToItemsAndSelectionValues(newItem.Key, newItem.Value);
            }
        }
        else if (this.ItemsSource is Dictionary<int, int>)
        {
            foreach (var newItem in (Dictionary<int, int>)this.ItemsSource)
            {
                this.AddToItemsAndSelectionValues(newItem.Key, newItem.Value);
            }
        }
        else if (this.ItemsSource is Dictionary<string, string>)
        {
            foreach (var newItem in (Dictionary<string, string>)this.ItemsSource)
            {
                this.AddToItemsAndSelectionValues(newItem.Key, newItem.Value);
            }
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    ///     Add the provided KeyValuePair to <see cref="Picker.Items" /> and <see cref="sourceDictionary" />
    /// </summary>
    private void AddToItemsAndSelectionValues(object key, object value)
    {
        this.Items.Add(this.ValueIsDisplayMember() ? value.ToString() : key.ToString());
        this.sourceDictionary.Add(this.ValueIsDisplayMember() ? key : value, new KeyValuePair<object, object>(key, value));
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you know that `ItemsSource` is a dictionary then you can simply cast it into `IDictionary` and iterate it because you just need objects and it gives you exacly that:

```
var items = (IDictionary)ItemsSource;
foreach (var key in items.Keys)
{
    AddToItemsAndSelectionValues(key, items[key]);
}
```

You cast it into a concrete dictionary but you never use the types anyway so go directly with objects instead.

That's all. You don't need any of those `if`s.

Comment: That worked quite excellent. Very elegant